# Show UILabel animated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation, uilabel

I need to show a message that appears with animation and hide after a few seconds also with animation.

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Thank you very much for everything.

regards

Comment: Check out the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438880/animating-uilabel-fade-in-out, which I think will meet your needs.

Comment: Use the given answer because the link above use a deprecated animation way. The given answer use blocks, which is a lot more intuitive and the apple recommended way of doing it from now on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its easy, try chaining your animations together. First fadeIn, then fadeOut. What below code does is first set `alpha` to 0. Then animate the appearance of the label in 1 sec. As soon as this is done, wait for 4 seconds, then start the fadeOut animation in the same manner.

```
[label setText:@"some text"];
[label setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^(void) 
 {
     [label setAlpha:1.0];
 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) 
 {
     if(finished)
     {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 
                               delay:4 
                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                          animations:^(void) 
          {
              [label setAlpha:0.0];
          } 
                          completion:^(BOOL finished) 
          {
              if(finished)
                  NSLog(@"Hurray. Label fadedIn & fadedOut");
          }];
     }
 }];
```

This way of chaining animation in iOS is one of the most effective ways to do so.